# My PHP code isn´t inserting the values into the Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make a code that will capture the data inside some form and insert it into my database in Wamp server, but for some reason it isn´t working even though I am sure I did it with a lot of care.

Here is the relevant code:

HTML

```
  <form id="frmLabs" method="post">
    <div class="divFormlabs">
      <label for="txtCapacidad">Capacidad</label>
      <input type="text" name="txtCapacidad" id="txtCapacidad">
      <label for ="txtCantEquipos">Carrera</label>

      <select type="text" name="txtCarrera" id="txtCarrera">
          <option value="Desarrollo">Desarrollo</option>
          <option value="Diseño">Diseño</option>
          <option value="Telematica">Telemática</option>
          <option value="T.I">T.I</option>
    </select>

    </div>

      <div class="divFormlabs">
      <label for="txtNumLab">Número de laboratorio</label>
      <input type="text" name="txtNumLab" id="txtNumLab">
      <label for="txtUbicacion">Ubicación</label>
      <input type="text" name="txtUbicacion" id="txtUbicacion">
    </div>
  </form>
```

jQuery

```
$("#btnAceptar").click(function() {
  var idlab = $('#txtNumLab').val(),
  capacidad = $('#txtCapacidad').val(),
  carrera = $('txtCarrera').val(),
  ubicacion = $('txtUbicacion').val();


var request = $.ajax({
 url: "includes/functionsLabs.php",
 type: "post",
 data: {

    'call': 'addLab',
    'pIdLab':idlab,
    'pCapacidad':capacidad,
    'pCarrera':carrera,
    'pUbicacion':ubicacion},

     dataType: 'json',

     success: function(response){
        alert('exito');
    }
  });
});
```

PHP

```
function addLab(){
if(isset($_POST['pIdLab']) && 
    isset($_POST['pCapacidad']) &&
    isset($_POST['pCarrera']) &&
    isset ($_POST['pUbicacion'])){

    $idlab = $_POST['pIdLab'];
    $capacidad = $_POST['pCapacidad'];
    $carrera = $_POST['pCarrera'];
    $ubicacion = $_POST['pUbicacion'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO labs VALUES" . "('$idlab', '$capacidad','$carrera',
 '$ubicacion')";

    $result = do_query($query);


}

}


 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
$function = $_POST['call'];
if(function_exists($function)) {        
    call_user_func($function);
} else {
    echo 'Function doesnt exists!';
}
   }



?>
```

The order of the rows in my database in the table Labs is exactly the one in the code:

IdLab
Capacidad
Carrera
Ubicacion

Also please forgive me for putting the variables in another languaje but it cannot be helped >.< Any kind of assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Best Wishes and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the code for btnAceptar.

```
<input class="formatButton verInfo2"  type="button" value="Aceptar"   id="btnAceptar"onclick="window.location='labs.html';" />
```

Comment: `$function = $_POST['call'];
if(function_exists($function)) { call_user_func($function);` Security hole..... very nasty people can cause some serious damage with this

Comment: First what I would do, is to print `$query` to check if it's fine. Try to execute it manually, then you will know what's going on, or at least you will be closer to the solution..

Comment: and the query is unsafe as well.  Have you checked that $_POST contains your data, eg `var_dump($_POST);`, and check to see if your query errors out also

Comment: There's no button with an id of `btnAceptar` in your form, are you sure your click handler is called?

Comment: I know the security is quite lax but this is just a practice for myself to start learning php. And yes btnAceptar does exist.

Comment: As far as the database is concerned, you should learn the right way from the start. Look for PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements in the php manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not assigning your variables correctly:

```
var idlab = $('#txtNumLab').val(),
  capacidad = $('#txtCapacidad').val(),
  carrera = $('txtCarrera').val(),
  ubicacion = $('txtUbicacion').val();
```

Note that the last two are missing the `#` in the selector, so your `if` condition in your php file will never be met.

You can replace the way you assign your data with:

```
data: $('#frmLabs').serialize(),
```

**Edit:** Note that because of the sql injection problem you have, your query could fail if one of the fields contains for example a `'` character.

Comment: Oh my... I will fix that asap and be back with you.

Comment: Wamp server keep loading without succes the phpMyAdmin so this may take awhile...

Comment: I fixed the # but it isn´t still working. And do you mean like:

data: $('#frmLabs').serialize(), and one for each field then?

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper You should check the developer tools of your browser for javascript errors / messages and the output of your php script.

Comment: I removed the onclick="window.location='labs.html';" from the btnAceptar and that made the trick.

Thanks a lor for your help, I will try to change my injection to mirror the one you gave me. Do I have to change anything else beside that to make it work your way?

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper No, but you should use for example a whitelist of allowed functions to avoid the problem mentioned by MarkBaker.

Answer (score 1):

first:

```
$("#btnAceptar").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
idlab = $('#txtNumLab').val(),
capacidad = $('#txtCapacidad').val(),
carrera = $('#txtCarrera').val(),
ubicacion = $('#txtUbicacion').val();


var request = $.ajax({
url: "includes/functionsLabs.php",
type: "post",
data: {
'call': 'addLab',
'pIdLab':idlab,
'pCapacidad':capacidad,
'pCarrera':carrera,
'pUbicacion':ubicacion},

 dataType: 'json',

 success: function(response){
    alert('exito');
   }
  });
});
```

Then in includes/functionsLabs.php:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

or:

```
echo $query;
```

And quit onclick="window.location='labs.html';" of you btnAceptar:

Recommended use firebug complement for test